# Low Variables — Batch Creation

Tags: low-variables

On the overview it mentions you can batch create low variables:

> You can clone variables, **batch-create** them and duplicate whole
>   groups

How is this done exactly? I'm having trouble finding any documentation.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Variable creation options](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables/docs/manage) bit. Batch creation of multiple identical vars happens when using multiple suffixes when creating a variable.